# Set custom postgres pid and log file

Tags: postgresql, config

I tried to set up new configs for my postgres, but for some reason I can't do it correctly.

First of my trying is to move `.pid` file to some other location, I can rename the file in `postgres.conf` but I can't set it to directory I need.
Same situation is with `.log` file.
Why when I tried to set pid file using `external_pid_file = '/home/vagrant/shared/pids/postgres.pid'` file isn't created? Or when I tried to set log file to `/home/vagrant/shared/logs` folder I have the same issue.
My config file:
https://pastebin.com/ud6HSJrn

Comment: Please give the exact sequence of commands you are using. You cannot change the pid file while the database is running.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe After restarting machine(using vagrant for development) I has the same problem